# Any methods for clustering short time series data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering, hierarchical-clustering, discrete-time

I have around 200 different sets of time series data with a semi-annual periodicity.
The length of each series varies from 1 to 6 years. 
I essentially want to build unsupervised clusters by grouping trends based on their magnitude and direction.
Are there any clustering approaches that would apply well to this scenario?

Comment: If this were my problem I would probably want to try modelling each series in terms of level, trend and seasonality and then look for clusters in the parameter space. I am sceptical that time series divide themselves into clusters unless that is obvious substantively, in which case a fancy method is not needed.

Comment: This seems reasonable, the only challenge being that the series is sparse in nature. Most trends have 6-10 datapoints at a semi-annual interval, so its difficult to obtain seasonality information.

Comment: If you start with level and trend parameters then that allows you to look at a scatter plot. If you don't see clear clustering on that graph the enterprise may be doomed.